# How best to merge data with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-2.0

I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction on this.  I have tried to isolate my question in as simple a form as I can think of.  In parsing a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Master>
    <Info>
        <Info1></Info1>
        <Info2></Info2>
        <Info3></Info3>
        <Offer>
            <Id>1a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>
            <Id>3a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
        </Offer>
    </Info>
</Master>
```

I need to compare it with a similar file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Old>
    <Info>
        <Info1></Info1>
        <Info2></Info2>
        <Info3></Info3>
        <Offer>
            <Id>1a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>
            <Id>2a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
        </Offer>
    </Info>
</Old>
```

Using the  field as a key, I would like to produce the following with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Merged>
    <Info>  ##from Master
        <Info1></Info1>
        <Info2></Info2>
        <Info3></Info3>
        <Offer>     ##from Master
            <Id>1a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
            <Action>Update</Action>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>     ##from Old
            <Id>2a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
            <Action>Delete</Action>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>     ##from Master
            <Id>3a</Id>
            <Field1></Field1>
            <Field2></Field2>
            <Field3></Field3>
            <Action>Add</Action>
         </Offer>
    </Info>
</Merged>
```

1a matches in both Master and Old so it becomes an update operation,  2a exists in Old but not Master do it becomes a delete operation and  3a only exists in Master so it thus becomes an add operation.  The  and  data always comes from the Master (except, of course in the delete case).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Before writing your own merge algorithm, try [Oliver Becker's](https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html). Let us know if it produces the output you want.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking at it and I am certainly no expert but it seems that it would require quite a bit of rework to yield the results I need.  I was looking at A intersect B (my update), A except B (my add), and B except A (my delete) as a possibility but I am not really sure how to apply it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems rather simple (or perhaps I misunderstand the requirement):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="master" select="document(base-uri())" />
<xsl:variable name="old" select="document('old.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="offer" match="Offer" use="Id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$old/Old/Info/Offer[not(key('offer', Id, $master))]" mode="delete"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Offer">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <Action>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="key('offer', Id, $old)">Update</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Add</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </Action>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Offer" mode="delete">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Action>Delete</Action>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The assumption here is that the Master.xml file is the one being processed.

Comment: The solution may in fact be simple but I am still learning.  I have run out of time today but will certainly look at your solution tomorrow and update.  Thanks again, it is certainly appreciated.

Comment: With the example provided, I was able to get it to work.